# DI studio: SAS attempting to remote signon to local for transformations

Tags: sas, sas-dis

Whenever I use a transformation directly on an oracle table in DI studio, the transformation is auto-generating a piece of code as below: (remote sign-on to local)

```
Options comamid =tcp
%let local=<servername> 7551;
Data _null_;
Signon local authdomain="DefaultAuth"
Run;
```

It throws an error similar as below:

```
User authentication failed at metadata server
A communication link was not set up...
```

My question is: earlier when I used Table loader or delete transform, such a remote sign to local code was not there. Why is SAS trying to remote connect using defaultauth metadata object on this server?

How to disable SAS from doing it?

Answer (score 3):

Your library is probably assigned to another application server than the one you are using in DI Studio. Try switching application server (right bottom of DI Studio) or assign a different application server to the library (library > properties > assign tab).

Comment: Same.  We noticed that when you have a new user profile, and you first open a job, you get asked which application server to use..  This then becomes the default.